# Ask for password when try to uninstall my java application in Windows

Tags: java, windows, desktop-application, uninstallation

I've made an installer of my java application for Windows. After installing it in Windows everything works perfectly. Now I want to add a feature which should **ask for a Password when I try to uninstall my Application** without password one must not be able to uninstall it.

One other thing that I want to know is, whether I need to make a separate uninstaller or I can add these functionalities in my installer itself?

Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S.** Here I'm targeting Windows OS to install applications.

> **In short, I want that if someone tries to uninstall my application, he prompted for a password and if he enters the right password then
>   and then he can able to uninstall it.**
>
> I don't know to achieve above want, whether I need to change my
>   installer or I need to create a custom uninstaller.

Comment: AM I understanding right that you wrote an "uninstaller" as a java program and now want to secure this program with a password?

Comment: No, I've just created an "Installer" only, I don't know how to create an "Uninstaller" if you know how to create Uninstaller please share the resources.

Comment: If you know the location where you installed your application, you could use `java.io.File.delete()` to delete all files you created.

Comment: @TA I'm finding some solution which asks for password at the time of uninstallation. I don't want to delete any files, actually I'm trying to make my installation more secure

Comment: Are you triggering the uninstallation process from ***within*** you application?

Comment: No, the uninstallation process will only trigger from Contol Panel -> Add or remove software (Like conventional uninstallation process)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable You might be right about XY Problem, I've updated my question, please check my actual want.

Comment: You merely reworded what looks to be your proposed solution, but what *problem* are you trying to solve by forcing a user to enter a password on uninstall?

Comment: yes, I want to force a user to enter a password on uninstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after so much effort I found some good source that explains to me all the questions.

In Inno Setup pascal script I can modify some code to achieve password protection like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=UninsPassword
AppVerName=UninsPassword
DisableProgramGroupPage=true
DisableStartupPrompt=true
DefaultDirName={pf}\UninsPassword

[Code]
function AskPassword(): Boolean;
var
  Form: TSetupForm;
  OKButton, CancelButton: TButton;
  PwdEdit: TPasswordEdit;
begin

  Result := false;
  Form := CreateCustomForm();
  try
    Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
    Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(100);
    Form.Caption := 'Uninstall Password';
    Form.BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu];
    Form.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
    Form.Center;

    OKButton := TButton.Create(Form);
    OKButton.Parent := Form;
    OKButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    OKButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 6 + 75 + 50);
    OKButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    OKButton.Caption := 'OK';
    OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk;
    OKButton.Default := true;

    CancelButton := TButton.Create(Form);
    CancelButton.Parent := Form;
    CancelButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    CancelButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 50);
    CancelButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel';
    CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
    CancelButton.Cancel := True;

    PwdEdit := TPasswordEdit.Create(Form);
    PwdEdit.Parent := Form;
    PwdEdit.Width := ScaleX(210);
    PwdEdit.Height := ScaleY(23);
    PwdEdit.Left := ScaleX(23);
    PwdEdit.Top := ScaleY(23);

    Form.ActiveControl := PwdEdit;

    if Form.ShowModal() = mrOk then
    begin
      Result := PwdEdit.Text = 'removeme';
      if not Result then
            MsgBox('Password incorrect: Uninstallation prohibited.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    Form.Free();
  end;
end;


function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := AskPassword();
end;
```

Source of information: [this post](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Require_an_uninstallation_password)